# How to add custom permission evaluator to oauth expression handler

Tags: security, oauth, spring-security

I got to know that the following is the way to add a custom permission evaluator

The problem in my case is i use  oauthexpressionhandler as shown below

```
<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler"/ >
```

I tried adding custom permission evaluator as shown below

```
<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled"  proxy-target-class="true">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" >
    <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
</oauth:expression-handler>
```

But i got the following error 
Element 'oauth:expression-handler' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty. when i try to call an API

Please let me know how can we add a permission evaluator when oauth expression handler is used.

Regards
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

You could add a setter to your PermissionEvaluator that receives the expression handler to modify it:

```
public void setExpressionHandler(final AbstractSecurityExpressionHandler<?> expressionHandler) {
    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(this);
}
```

Then in the XML pass the expression handler to the evaluator when creating it:

```
<bean class="my.package.MyPermissionEvaluator" >
    <property name="expressionHandler" ref="oauthExpressionHandler"/>
</bean>
```

Seems like there should be a better way though.